# Getting 405 http status code from making requests of modifying statuses to Uber Sandbox

Tags: ios, uber-api

Firstly I made a `POST /v1/requests` to Uber sandbox with my valid access token and Uber returned `202 OK` to me, meaning the request was successful.

Then I made requests trying to manipulate the status of a Request with `PUT /v1/sandbox/requests/{request_id}`, but I could only get `405` code.

I've tried all the statuses and the results were all `405`, please help see if there are any possible causes. Thanks.

I make my request for changing status (`PUT /v1/sandbox/requests/{request_id}`) with the following:

```
NSString *url = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/requests/%@", sandBoxURL, requestId];
NSDictionary *params = @{@"status": @"processing"};

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];
[request addValue:@"application/json; charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request addValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Bearer %@", _accessToken] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];

NSError *error = nil;
request.HTTPMethod = @"PUT";
request.HTTPBody = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:params options:0 error:&error];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32048746/uber-api-endpoints-not-working-with-real-server-domain-but-working-well-with-san) is another similar question I posted and I have got the answer from Uber support officially.

It turned out that in my location, which is China, the full production Uber API has not been fully launched.

That's why anyone in China would get such weird response codes.

This is duplicate, please feel free to delete this post if necessary.