# Uber API endpoints not working with real server domain but working well with sandbox

Tags: ios, https, uber-api

I have been testing Uber API for a month and I have seen some unstable behaviors recently.

In my code there are some unusual response returned from Uber endpoints. Now I am pasting the screen shots of my code here below:

You can see I have a global string type variable "baseURL", I keep switching it between real server and sandbox as below:
"https://api.uber.com/v1" and "https://sandbox-api.uber.com/v1"

But from my testing result, I can tell that most the API in sandbox work perfectly well but when I switched to the real server domain, all of the ones that I have tested did not work at all.

**Update:**
For the sandbox environment, `/v1/estimates/time` does not work either. It would return `401`. 
My request url is like this: `https://sandbox-api.uber.com/v1/estimates/time?server_token=myToken&start_latitude=39.914097&start_longitude=116.458539`.

1) `POST /v1/request/estimate`

I am sure "POST" is what the Uber API doc suggests (https://developer.uber.com/v1/endpoints/). But this screen shot was taken when I switched to the real server (sandbox works no problem with the same code).

It returned: `"Method not supported for this endpoint."` / `"method_not_allowed"` with `405 code`.

[image]

2) `POST /v1/requests`

Same behavior with the real server (sandbox works good) like below, and it also returned `"invalid OAuth 2.0 credentials provided."` / `"unauthorized"` with `405 code`. But I'm sure I can use the same credentials to make requests in sandbox.

[image]

3) `GET /v1/estimates/time`

Even this API, it doesn't require access token but still returned `"No authentication provided."` / `"unauthorized"` with `401 code`.
Please note that it works well for the sandbox but fails for the real server.

[image]

Please help, many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everyone can use the Uber API Request endpoint in the sandbox environment, but using it in production requires whitelisting. You can request your app to be whitelisted on the Uber support page: https://developer.uber.com/support/.

For the /v1/estimates/time endpoint, a server token or an access token is required in production, but no whitelisting is required for this.

Comment: Hey Alec, thanks for your explanation. All of them, including production and sandbox, were working well like a month ago, without requiring whitelisting. Do you mean that now the procedure has been updated?

Comment: And for the `/v1/estimates/time` if you take a look at my screen shot, you can see a server token has been added to the request url but it still returned `401`.

Comment: I printed the url like this: `https://api.uber.com/v1/estimates/time?server_token=myToken&start_latitude=39.914277&start_longitude=116.460496`.

Comment: I see that 39.9‌​14277, 116.460496 is located in China. We haven't fully launched API support in China yet but the team is working hard on this. Please look out for further announcements on http://devblog.uber.com/.

Comment: well that seems to be a bad news to me...so do you mean that all of the production API are unavailable in China or just this one?

Comment: The various endpoints for the production API may not work as expected until we've fully launched in China.

Comment: Yeah, ok, I get it. I guess Chinese developers have to wait for a while then. Thanks a lot for all the help!

Comment: Update: The Uber API is now available in China!

Comment: @Alec how to get the server token to use uber sandbox apis ? i searched in the uber tutorials but i found nothing ,thanks in advance